# Concatenating according interconnected attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Need to concatenate 3-x level child-parent relation in two parallel ways.

1 - Output with full levels concatenation

2 - Output with Dividing according level

**source code**

```
<A>
  <X id="top"                        text="first"  text2="*"/>
  <X id="middle" id-parent="top"     text="second" text2="**"/>
  <X id="bottom" id-parent='middle"' text="third"  text2="***"/>
</A>
```

Current XSLT code partly solve second option.It divide according level, but level postfix' calculation is not tied to hierarchy's computation. The bottom (lower) level is not displayed. Also The order of the output levels inverse to the desired.

**xslt transformation**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

      <xsl:key name="ref" match="X" use="@id"/>
      <xsl:template match="X">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', @id-parent)" mode="att"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="X" mode="att">
        <xsl:param name="pos" select="count(@*) + 1"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="level-{$pos}">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(@text,' ', '| ', @text2)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('ref', @id-parent)" mode="att">
          <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos + 1"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

inteconnection [scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKMCv.jpg)

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRAoS/1

**desired ouput**

```
<A>   <!-- KIND OF-->
  <X id="top"                        text="first"  text2="*"   chain-text="first *"                         level-1="first | *" /> <!-- however, this upper level may remain as in the base source and don't be changed -->
  <X id="middle"  id-parent="top"    text="second" text2="**"  chain-text="first * | second **"             level-1="first | *" level-2="second | **"/>
  <X id="bottom"  id-parent="middle" text="third"  text2="**"  chain-text="first * | second ** | third ***" level-1="first | *" level-2="second | **" level-3="third | ***"/>
</A>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="X" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="X">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="Xs">
            <xsl:call-template name="XATT">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentX" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="X" select=".">
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$Xs[node()]">
                <xsl:attribute name="chain-text">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$Xs/X">
                        <xsl:if test="position() ne 1"><xsl:text> | </xsl:text></xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@text, ' ', @text2)"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="$Xs/X">
                    <xsl:attribute name="level-{position()}"><xsl:value-of select="concat(@text, ' | ', @text2)"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="XATT">
        <xsl:param name="currentX"/>
        <xsl:param name="X"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$currentX/@id-parent">
                <xsl:call-template name="XATT">
                    <xsl:with-param name="currentX" select="key('ref', $currentX/@id-parent)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="X">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ref', $currentX/@id-parent)"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$X"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$X"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRAoS/2

Comment: Its a part of a more complex task, divided into parts. I am going to post additional condition. Hope they could be well-integrated into your code.